# how to get variable in controller of angularjs

Tags: angularjs

My controller:

```
 angular.module('myApp.view2', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/view2', {
        templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
        controller: 'View2Ctrl'
      });
    }])
    .controller('View2Ctrl', [$scope, function(){
        $scope.country = {
            name:"USA",
            age:500,
            year:100
        }

    }]);
```

view

```
<div ng-controller="View2Ctrl">
    {{ country.name }}
</div>
```

My html when i call {{ country.name }} it return string : "{{ country.name }}"

Comment: can you post view2.html?

Comment: post your complete code for the view and other controllers